# jquery .not() is not working with live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding some dom with ajax in a page where i am trying to excluding seleted result by `.not()` but its not working for me.

**Here is a simple example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-item">
        <span class="item-title">Some title</span>
        <span class="edit fr"><a href="Edit link">Edit</a></span>
        <span class="trash fr"><a href="#trashit" rel="trash">Trash</a></span>
        <span class="live fr active"><a href="#liveit" rel="publish">Live</a></span>
        <span class="draft fr"><a href="#draftit" rel="draft">Draft</a></span>

 </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.list-item span a').not('.list-item span.edit a').live('click', function(){

       //do stuff
});
```

**Observation:**

1. If i remove the `.not()` section of the code the selection is works fine with `live()`.
2. If i use `.not()` but replace `live()` with `click()` the code works.

But i need to run the `.not()` (exclude the `.edit` class) with the `live();` (including dom with ajax)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [the `.live()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live#caveats):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to `.live()`. Rather, the `.live()` method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

---

So, add the class exclusion to the selector:

```
jQuery('.list-item span:not(.edit) a').live('click', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('.list-item span:not(.edit) a').live(...);
```

As someone else pointed out, DOM traversal is not supported for live. live has some other restrictions too, check the doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.list-item').filter(function(){

return $(this).not("span.edit a")
})
.live('click', function(){

       //do stuff
});
```